# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException assigning to charArrayOf()

Tags: kotlin

Could someone help me to understand where I've gone wrong because it seems that I keep on getting this error:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0

```
fun main()
{

    arrayOfNulls<String?>(size = 11)
    var firstWord : String?

    print("Enter in the sentence ")
    var strAnagram : String = readLine()!!

    var arrUserInput = strAnagram.split(" ")
    var  arrFirstLetter = charArrayOf()

    for(x in 0..arrUserInput.size+1)
    {
        firstWord = arrUserInput.get(x)
        arrFirstLetter[x] = firstWord[0]

    }

    for (y in 0..11)
    {
    println(arrFirstLetter[y])
    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to make acronyms, not anagrams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `var  arrFirstLetter = charArrayOf()` you are creating an empty array.

Then when you write `arrFirstLetter[x] = firstWord[0]`, you are trying to assign to the element at index `x` of an empty array. Because the array is empty, this is generating `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

In general it's better to avoid trying to loop over collections by using their index and instead use a [for loop](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#for-loops) or the [map](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html) extension function.

You can print out the first letters of each word like this:

```
fun main() {
    print("Enter in the sentence ")
    val userInputWords: List<String> = readLine()?.split(" ") ?: emptyList()

    for (word in userInputWords) {
        println("First letter: ${word[0]}")
    }
}
```

Comment: I missed the case where the input contains an empty string. It's more complex, but you can cover that with `for (word in userInputWords.filter { it.isNotEmpty() })`